# FCM notification in IOS ionic 4

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I updated IOS SDK to 14.4 and MAC OS also been updated.
All of a sudden FCM stopped working, it was working perfectly fine.
I am not understanding what exactly went wrong.

1.Since, fcm token is been triggered and registering in database as well.
2.Tried  triggering from firebase console but still unable to receive notification, but in android it works fine.
3. Tried to trigger from our backend application (Dot Net), it gives Success:1 Failure:0

plugins used are cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated

import {FCM} from "cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" declared in app.components.ts

Any help, will we be much appreciated.

Comment: have try POD install inside your ios platform folder.